# Emails go to spam ( Reverse DNS is set , DKIM pass , SPF pass , DMARC pass )

Tags: email, vps, dkim, spf

It's been now 3 days that I am struggling with configuring my emails to go to the inbox.

I have a VPS server at OVH and a domain name. I have configured everything in virtualmin with OpenDKIM and Postfix and used various check tools and everything seems okay (as shown in this screenshot from the Gmail email) but the emails still go to spam ( Yahoo, Hotmail , Gmail ).

[image: Screenshot of the email's details received by gmail]

Here are the details of a test message sent to Yahoo. As shown, the email is signed and everything seems okay.

```
X-Apparently-To: nabil.jahir@yahoo.com; Sat, 24 Nov 2018 16:33:22 +0000
Return-Path: <onlineportfolio@onlineportfolio.pro>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 51.75.31.162
Received-SPF: pass (domain of onlineportfolio.pro designates 51.75.31.162 as permitted sender)
X-YMailISG: UMSYaSMWLDtCAbV4UOzfJPY8yYEmqasl9uS0CNCWQntZxG6M
 Fw6igajRZYFVNN.FU7eUuLVuUbBmv8lFUM0RbkU0s.73TLyFu2IZfAN0ZEov
 yQ.tdV13b.3qc_on.gyqnfa4_19bGlEUb_UUTMULgkfYb0yEoSUqdzy_8CLw
 GwFgHO9neZeCKQ8AvDSXa3g8v_Qa40x7QvK8EAzLLiUJ_Kn8rQotnMwmp7hN
 Zm858LGbPSDCGjYTa361wcT7agiIWwtzynbYu97ZseIEKW2RJbKWbVi59JI1
 C0fl1i_XqyTam52bsd8ql2B_84h9jEGr644BIpltsOA6E4IxP1NAXxdkGGoR
 Y1OxWS94_pFHHR0rZDZXjF2YYJoCApDNqlHrP7ZKxlFYFGyzNuFVjFixd5Ki
 kNZytf0GiOaCGrKDkJBzR3HT1bUK9pwiM2jPAXv0h.PNBWWTOc13p_jSqhEx
 46zsxGpf2l.oIL24OxrXtDwAwth1dAvgHLz_mt_hHXzLuNm1pAJbc4bwS.UL
 wnFkJn9Ldc4tZ7j5YgxznNxSDvvWm7xjPkWNNL.OhfI1N0_GrRxkM0ADPkl2
 YgK6THvVic4s3eLw3E91M8tqpb0zQh3M23yAvi4eaI.nVjweS.Q1LZvybbwI
 W3sNsRGY_Ydhoxpeu0Nzro8jF4OPy6EFYeGcH2T7tDsCCgc0N0ncrRVPkQ27
 9rGqFtRh5yNluX0K9wIGQU2vn63c41D5hLs5WFAlvBficYVE2py0FL5L94.n
 WrFrMqHDgAuEW2Iy6_qPNAWUJDpIJykrsGI2ph9g02KhLzTL4B4S59TH4X8W
 xVgYCu13zRMB7kfcyM0QXZsV1uxSIBi8Ewku3zWuu3lwqfNFDsHU6w6k7P1h
 fVgg_nRNjSXKNT24qqSQUh2jJWFQlanGwKLkhDCpiBxEoQgr84OUo13hdjap
 YnY7ncw1iOBlKudLxJc029WYtH.ukMbMEsa03soD7ihS97rb3tLz6GxrDqo3
 Sq.GP.krEjUdJAAB0VYG63LAmeFAoy6yrDRB60A9Zdlu_IORPautWynT2MNz
X-Originating-IP: [51.75.31.162]
Authentication-Results: mta4434.mail.ne1.yahoo.com  from=onlineportfolio.pro; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=onlineportfolio.pro; dkim=pass (ok)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO vps590830.ovh.net) (51.75.31.162)
  by mta4434.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Sat, 24 Nov 2018 16:33:21 +0000
Received: from onlineportfolio.pro (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by vps590830.ovh.net (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 1AA6E7F98C
    for <nabil.jahir@yahoo.com>; Sat, 24 Nov 2018 17:33:19 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=onlineportfolio.pro;
    s=mail; t=1543077199;
    bh=lJB/nYL/lnJN4VoNZZF46fk1OIxhohTSP6uovXwnXY8=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject;
    b=yocLTdOVKGS8kMbxBeHao07IHZF6tc021mMBro7TTLhfZnDlgIgZesZ1uXHT3cmuQ
     1AJBh0MBHnFt35j1VrlAOT+16qwAjq9QGO3vyHfW3rOSmMAOifU9pv+zsizYHpKno0
     OlQXSplwOwMPxmjaQ7CxqX4BrpPjcJo1+xzaz4dkDXrQ6EU83UEElLseOlrux2k3r5
     OGybMbxkW4uttUYjEhao06GiW5EGsplDfqG67trjOOvg5n7cc54FwxLvKRAa+EC+k8
     085lCvxR8jjeeFQTDpCDInARfBPhYNkk15jgsqMo8HmfC1bRGPcZifzm9WaoZcQCkq
     NzcI1PknzIEmw==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Sat, 24 Nov 2018 17:33:19 +0100
From: onlineportfolio <onlineportfolio@onlineportfolio.pro>
To: nabil.jahir@yahoo.com
Subject: Meeting
Message-ID: <ae4b023de1cf4d278e9106fd356c75fc@onlineportfolio.pro>
X-Sender: onlineportfolio@onlineportfolio.pro
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.3.8
Content-Length: 93

Dear sir,

Thank you very much for you kindness , we appreciate it very much.

Best regards.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 51.75.31.162
```

Yahoo seems to be indicating that your IP address is responsible for sending bulk mail.

I checked your IP address against several blacklists and it’s ok.

Quite simply, you don’t have enough reputation to be a trusted sender yet. You will need to exhibit a positive sending history to reduce your chances of being sent to junk mail. This is not uncommon for brand new IPs sending mail.